# What is the difference between a variable holding a public decorator vs not having one at all?

Tags: apex

```
public class TestClass{

Map<String, List<String>> leadFields;
public Map<String, List<String>> conFields;

public TestClass(){
    leadFields = new Map<String, List<String>>();
    conFields = new Map<String, List<String>>();
}

}
```

I am trying to understand the difference between the leadFields and conFields variables. I know they are drastically different, but the code runs the same for me - So I am struggling to understand there fundamental difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These aren't decorators; they're [access modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm).

The default access in Apex is `private`:

> This is the default, and means that the method or variable is accessible only within the Apex class in which it is defined. If you do not specify an access modifier, the method or variable is private.

Code within the same class is unaffected by access modifiers, which is why you see no effect on your code within `TestClass`. They apply only to external references and to subclasses. (Subclasses can access `protected` members of their superclasses, but not `private` members).

Some external caller of `TestClass` would be able to access `conFields`, but not `leadFields`.

Getters and setters on [properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) are subject to access modification too, which can allow you to achieve finer-grained access control. For example, the following declaration:

```
 public Integer myInt { get; private set; }
```

results in a property that is publicly readable, but writable only by code within the class. The access modifier of the member variable is by default also the access modifier of the associated getter and setter methods, but can be overridden as above.

Comment: Now what happens if I add a get; set; to these?

Comment: I'll expand upon my answer; just a sec.

Comment: A bit of extra exposition... "decorator" has a specific meaning in the software engineering world. It's a design pattern which I think can be broken down to "this child class overrides a method from its parent class. It adds some functionality, then calls the same method in the parent class so that the parent class's functionality is also applied."

Comment: The decorator pattern can also have more specific, concrete meanings in different stacks, e.g. a decorator is a specific construct in Python that Apex doesn't have, although one could implement the decorator pattern in Apex.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern